# Is there an omnibus for the entire Blackest Night and Brightest Day story arcs?

Tags: dc

I really wanted to read all the comics that dealt with this story arc (and I hear ALL of them did) and I was wondering if there was an omnibus available for me to buy, or if there isnt, which specifically are the issues that were included in this story?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there isn't one omnibus available, and the larger *Blackest Night* event covered a nearly unwieldy [amount of issues](http://comicbookdb.com/storyarc.php?ID=3350). *Brightest Day* is a [similar story](http://comicbookdb.com/storyarc.php?ID=3958).

That being said, both stories have been collected in a ton of collections. The titular collections contain the issues of the main eponymous series, while the rest cover spin-offs.

**Blackest Night**

- [Blackest Night](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=205233)
- [Blackest Night: Tales of the Corps](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=206875)
- [Blackest Night: Black Lantern Corps vol 1](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=206567)
- [Blackest Night: Black Lantern Corps vol 2](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=206569)
- [Blackest Night: Rise of the Black Lanterns](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=206539)
- [Green Lantern vol 7: Blackest Night](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=205232)
- [Green Lantern Corps vol 6: Blackest Night](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=205282)

**Brightest Day**

- [Brightest Day vol 1](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=216042)
- [Brightest Day vol 2](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=226712)
- [Brightest Day vol 3](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=234080)
- [Green Lantern Corps vol 8: Brightest Day - The Weaponer](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=239972)
- [Justice League: Generation Lost vol 1](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=225866)
- [Justice League: Generation Lost vol 2](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=239973)
- [Titans vol 4: Villains For Hire](http://comicbookdb.com/issue.php?ID=240041)

Answer (score 2):

They are releasing a brightest day omnibus in September. 2014

Comment: Can you back this up with a quote or link?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the Brightest Day Omnibus.

[https://www.amazon.com/Brightest-Day-Omnibus-Geoff-Johns/dp/1401245978/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401245978)

Comment: Could you show how/why you think this is the answer? We don't like link answers, it is better to quote the relevant information from the link, then use the actual link as a source.

Comment: I was trying to add the link to the comment from Brett White and Zod/Valorum, but I couldn't add the link as a reply to those comments. That's why I commented just the link.